# Timer running under bash script in dialog window

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, dialog

The following bash script is an example on how to use the dialog command. This script runs a progress bar (and displays the process upgrade). What is missing in the dialog is a **time clock** - that displays how much time the progress bar has been running, every second, until the end.

I am not sure if the dialog enables this, so I ask if it is possible to print the clock inside the dialog window?

If not, what are other alternatives? (for example, a clock that runs outside the dialog window)

```
  #!/bin/bash
  declare PACKAGES=("/etc/crontab"  "/etc/dmtab"  "/etc/fstab"  "/etc/inittab"  "/etc/mtab")
     NUM_PACKAGES=${#PACKAGES[*]} # no. of packages to update (#packages in the array $PACKAGES)
  step=$((100/$NUM_PACKAGES))  # progress bar step
   cur_file_idx=0
   counter=0
 DEST=${HOME}
    (
    # infinite while loop
    while :
  do
  cat <<EOF
  XXX
 $counter
   $counter% upgraded

   $COMMAND
   XXX
   EOF
       COMMAND="cp ${PACKAGES[$cur_file_idx]} $DEST &>/dev/null" # sets/updates command to exec.
      [[ $NUM_PACKAGES -lt $cur_file_idx ]] && $COMMAND # executes command

   (( cur_file_idx+=1 )) # increase counter
     (( counter+=step ))
   [ $counter -gt 100 ] && break  # break when reach the 100% (or greater
                               # since Bash only does integer arithmetic)
   sleep 10 # delay it a specified amount of time i.e. 1 sec
 done
     ) |
      dialog --title "File upgrade" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 70 0
```

***UPDATE:*** I also found some timer code and I want to combine this code in the dialog line - how do I do this?

*The timer script (code) :*

```
 date1=`  date   +%s`; 
   while true; do 
   echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r"; 
   done
```

Comment: I don't believe a countdown timer is possible, as the system on which this is running is likely to be non-deterministic...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it would be nice if dialog had a `--show-elapsed` option or something, it's not straightforward to do this currently.

The display part is not too hard: you can (ab)use the `--title` option to display the elapsed time. You can even get it to display below the gauge by adding more `\n` (and changing the box size).

[image]

More tricky is to get it to display every second even if there's 50s between status updates. Here's a solution using `read -t` timeout option:

```
#!/bin/bash

show_dialog()
{
    p=0             # percentage
    date1=`date +%s`
    while [ "$p" != 100 ]; do
        read -t 1 tmp && p=$tmp
        elapsed="$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)"
        echo $p | dialog --title "File upgrade" --gauge "Please wait...\n\n\n\n$elapsed" 10 70 0
    done
}

task()              # fake task
{ for p in `seq 1 100`; do echo $p; sleep 2; done; }

task | show_dialog
```